# Composer Uncaught Error: Class 'Instasent\SMSCounter\SMSCounter' not found

Tags: php, installation, composer-php

i have folder `/home/wira/wirdev/smscounter`,
in that folder i'm installing sms counter from https://github.com/instasent/sms-counter-php , installation completed. now inside of my folder is like this :

```
.
├── checkSMSSegment.php
├── composer.json
├── composer.lock
├── sms.txt
├── tesSMSLength.php
└── vendor
    ├── autoload.php
    ├── composer
    │   ├── autoload_classmap.php
    │   ├── autoload_namespaces.php
    │   ├── autoload_psr4.php
    │   ├── autoload_real.php
    │   ├── autoload_static.php
    │   ├── ClassLoader.php
    │   ├── installed.json
    │   └── LICENSE
    └── instasent
        └── sms-counter-php
            ├── composer.json
            ├── LICENSE-MIT
            ├── phpunit.xml.dist
            ├── README.md
            ├── SMSCounter.php
            └── Tests
                └── SMSCounterTest.php
```

this is code i want to run (`tesSMSLength.php`) :

```
<?php
use Instasent\SMSCounter\SMSCounter;

$text = file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__)."/sms.txt");

$smsCounter = new SMSCounter();
$result = $smsCounter->count($text);

print_r($result);
```

Now i want to run my code using this library  by typing `sudo php tesSMSLength.php`, but it shows ERROR class not found like this :

```
[wira@DevWira smscounter]$ sudo php tesSMSLength.php
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Instasent\SMSCounter\SMSCounter' not found in /home/wira/wirdev/smscounter/tesSMSLength.php:6
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /home/wira/wirdev/smscounter/tesSMSLength.php on line 6
```

What i'm missing here?

this is `composer.json` contents :

```
{
    "require": {
       "instasent/sms-counter-php": "^0.4"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Instasent\\SMSCounter\\": ""
        }
    },
}
```

Comment: You forgot to import the autoloader into your test file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your code is a CLI script, you're missing the autoload import at the top of the file:

```php
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Instasent\SMSCounter\SMSCounter;

...
```

Also, since `instasent/sms-counter-php` already includes `autoload` configuration in its `composer.json` file, you don't have to include it yourself in your `composer.json`.